# Why the token is displayed as 'end' type instead of STRING?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

my aim is save a comment that start with any word and end with the "end" word like this

> **ANYWORD** bla bla bla **end**

I have this grammar:

```
lexer grammar JunkLexer;
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
LQUOTE : 'start' -> more, mode(START) ;
mode START;
STRING : 'end' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // token we want parser to see
TEXT : . -> more ; // collect more text for string
```

but I don't know why, the lexer generates tokens that does not exists in the grammar:

[image]

when I checkout the lexer tokens, is the same:

```
WS=1
STRING=2
LQUOTE=3
'start'=3
'end'=2
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your question why the token is displayed as having type `'end'` instead of `STRING`?

Comment: Yes, that is my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a lexer rule using a single string literal, that string literal becomes an alternative name for the rule. So when you define `FOO: 'foo';` in the lexer grammar, you can then use `FOO` and `'foo'` interchangeably in the parser grammar. This allows you to use string literals in your grammar even if you split it up into a parser and lexer grammar. So even though you have to write `PLUS: '+';` in the lexer, you can still write `exp '+' exp` instead of `exp PLUS exp` in the grammar. The string literal name is also the one used when displaying the token because that tends to be more readable.

Of course that makes sense in the `PLUS` example, but doesn't really make sense in your example because, due to the `more`, your `STRING` rule doesn't actually just match `end`, but a whole string. So writing `'end'` in the parser grammar to match a complete begin-end section would be utterly confusing (though it would work) and so is the fact that it's used as the token name. However ANTLR doesn't realize that because it doesn't realize that `STRING` can only be reached through rules invoking `more`.

Note that you can still use `STRING` to refer to the token, so this won't actually break your grammar in any way. It will lead to confusing error messages though ("missing 'end'" when it should be "missing STRING").

To work around that you can change the `STRING` rule to not only consist of a single string literal:

```
STRING: 'e' 'n' 'd';
```

This will be equivalent in every way, except that `'end'` will no longer be an alias for `STRING` and will no longer be used as the display name of the token.